# Inheritance mapping by overriding property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have following code.

```
public class Person
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{        
}
```

With configuration

```
Map(p => p.MapInheritedProperties());
Property(p => p.LastName).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
```

And want to change it to

```
public class Person
{
        public virtual string LastName {get; set;}
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public override string LastName
    {
       get { return base.LastName; }
       set 
       {
             //add validation here or throw exception
             base.LastName = value;
       }
    }
}
```

If I run the application it says that the model has been changed.
Fine, I add a DB Migration, but it errors:

> The property 'LastName' is not a declared property on type 'Employee'.
>
> Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the
>
> Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.

What kind of mapping do I need to add for this to work?
I use EF 4.3 with Migrations.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Does the class People really only have one property LastName? When I try to reproduce I need to specify a key.

Comment: Does it make a difference if `LastName` on `Person` is declared as `virtual`?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a limitation of EF- properties can either be on the base class or the subclasses, but not both. See [How to share common column names in a Table per Hierarchy (TPH) mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389227/entity-framework-4-ctp5-code-first-how-to-share-common-column-names-in-a-hierar)

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround that:

```
public class Person
{
    protected virtual void ValidateLastName() { }

    public string LastName
    {
       get { return lastName; }
       set 
       {
             ValidateLastName();
             lastName = value;
       }
    }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    protected override void ValidateLastName()
    {
        // your validation logic here
    }
}
```