# Entity Framework 6 & TPH inheritance: Map properties with the same name to same column by default

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, table-per-hierarchy

As of EF6 it is possible to do something like this when configuring Entity mappings using Table Per Hierarchy inheritance:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ABatteryPoweredDevice>().Property(c => c.BatteryLevel).HasColumnName("BatteryLevel");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ADifferentBatteryPoweredDevice>().Property(c => c.BatteryLevel).HasColumnName("BatteryLevel");
    }
}
```

`BatteryLevel` is not part of the `Device` base class- it is a property of the derived classes implemented to fulfill an interface contract.

Is it possible to make this the default behavior as opposed to having to add a new mapping for each derived class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Used [Custom Code First Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx), which are available from EF6 onwards, to sort this out:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //your code before
        modelBuilder.Properties().Configure(prop => prop.HasColumnName(prop.ClrPropertyInfo.Name));
        //your code after
    }
```

This maps properties with the same name in different derived types to the same table column without explicit calls like those mentioned in the question.

Comment: Is there any way to configure this only for a table in EF6? I try to use Properties<Table>() and even create a derived class consisting of every columns in the DB table to use Properties<FullTable>(), but nothing works. Setting Properties() would affect all tables in the DB and I don't want that to override existing configuration.