# Table per Hierarchy table mapping with both shared and unshared columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, table-per-hierarchy

This is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389227/how-to-share-common-column-names-in-a-table-per-hierarchy-tph-mapping) which from what I can tell now works in EF6. However, it seems as though there's a problem when you've got subclasses which have both shared and unshared properties.

Let's say this is my model setup:

```
public abstract class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NameOnDocument { get; set; }
}

public class BirthCertificate : Document
{
    public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Licence : Document
{
    public string LicenceNumber { get; set; }
}
```

In the database, I want `BirthCertificate.RegistrationNumber` and `Licence.LicenceNumber` to share the same column, `Number`. As such, I'm setting up my model like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // Document - base class
    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().HasKey(d => d.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
        .Property(d => d.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
        .Property(d => d.NameOnDocument)
        .HasColumnName("Name");

    // Birth certificate
    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().Map<BirthCertificate>(map => 
        map.Property(c => c.RegistrationNumber).HasColumnName("Number"));

    // Licence
    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().Map<Licence>(map => 
        map.Property(l => l.LicenceNumber).HasColumnName("Number"));
}
```

When I generate the database, it all looks and works as expected:

[image: DB Model]

Now for the issue at hand. Let's say the `Licence` entity also needs to record an expiry date; so I add that in as follows:

```
public class Licence : Document
{
    public string LicenceNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I regenerate the database, it looks like this:

[image]

What's more, if I try to insert a licence and a birth certificate, I get the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: A value shared across entities or associations is generated in more than one location. Check that mapping does not split an EntityKey to multiple store-generated columns.

I can understand why that exception is raised - because the database is useless.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that the problem is simple to solve, and yet so far as I can tell is not documented anywhere. So hopefully this will help someone with the same problem.

Seemingly, the key is that **you have to map *every* property on the derived entity**:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().Map<Licence>(map =>
{
    map.Property(l => l.LicenceNumber).HasColumnName("Number");
    map.Property(l => l.ExpiryDate).HasColumnName("ExpiryDate");
});
```

Now my database generates as I would expect and all is right with the world.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are gaining much by putting 2 columns into 1 in the database. I don't think you'll save much space and you can't interrogate the `Number` of a base `Document`, even though both documents will have one. Have you considered adding the `Number` field to the base and using data annotations on overrides - something like this?

```
public abstract class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NameOnDocument { get; set; }
    public virtual string Number
}

public class BirthCertificate : Document
{
    [Display(Name="Registration Number"]
    [Required]
    public override string Number { get; set; }
}

public class Licence : Document
{
    [Display(Name="Licence Number"]
    [Required]
    public override string Number { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT** And if all documents aren't numbered:

```
public abstract class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NameOnDocument { get; set; }
}

public abstract class NumberedDocument : Document
{
    public virtual string Number
}

public class BirthCertificate : NumberedDocument
{
    [Display(Name="Registration Number"]
    [Required]
    public override string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This was a stripped down example of a bigger problem though... There are actually about 6 document types which each share about 5 common properties plus a handful of semi-common properties. Not all documents have a number. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @gerrod edited to show how to use inheritance for "semi-common" properties

Comment: Thanks; but that's still too simple :-). Its more like - in conjunction with the common properties, my table has seven possibly shared properties - PropertyA, PropertyB.... PropertyG.

Document1 has PropertyA, PropertyC.
Document2 has PropertyC, PropertyE, PropertyF.
Document3 has PropertyB, PropertyE, PropertyG. etc etc

Six different document types, each with a different combination of the shared properties.